# Algebra: Translating a problem into an equation

Tags: arithmetic

How would I go about to translate this problem into an equation?
*I've translated problems in to equations before, but never this kind of problem. I'm quite new to algebra.*

**You are going to arrange chairs in rows. There should be an equal amount of chairs in each row.**

**If you arrange the chairs in 5 rows there will be 12 chairs over.**

**If you arrange the chairs in 7 rows there will be 4 more chairs needed to complete the rows (which you don't have).**

**How many chairs should it be in every row?**

I tried to write it like this: **X / 5 = X / 7 + 8** and then I solved for **X** from there (and found the "answer"), but the equation in question is of course not right to begin with.

**Edit:**

I'm not looking for the answer or how to solve the equation, just how to translate the problem *into* an equation. I hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: $X=5n+12$ and $X=7m-4$. For this, you will get a whole set of answers. Have you heard of modulo before?

Comment: Are the number of columns constant or can they vary?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes I am familiar with it from programming. 7%5=2, right?

Comment: Ok then. We have $X = 12 \pmod 5$ and $X=-4 \pmod 7$. We can simplify this to $X=2 \pmod 5$ and $X= 3 \pmod 7$.  Now we have to use the Chinese Remainder theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to always watch out for invariants, that is, non changing quantities. Here, there are two -- the total number of chairs to be arranged, and the number of chairs in each row.

Let the number of chairs in each row be $n$ and the total number of chairs be $N.$ Then from the third sentence we have that $N$ has been partitioned as $5n+12.$ Thus we have $$N=5n+12.$$ Similarly, from the next statement we have that $$N=7n-4.$$

Thus we deduce the equation $$5n+12=7n-4,$$ which we want to solve for $n.$